# Change AAD Social login button text n B2C login page

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have an application authenticating with AzureAD B2C with a signin policy. Users can sign in with Local B2C accounts, or via OpenIdConnect to a an azure B2C tenant. I have a customized login page were the signin/signup form gets injected into `<div id="api"/>`. The sign in page looks like this:

[image: Sign in type selection]

I am able to hide some elements I don't want shown with CSS like so:

e.g.:

```
div.social div.intro {
    display:none
}
```

Originally, I added some javascript to the custom login page to change the text with a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). However, the javascript is filtered out by the B@C signin process..

I was able to successfully change the Local login button by [customizing the localization JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization) like so:

```
{
  "ElementType": "ClaimsProvider",
  "ElementId": null,
  "StringId": "SignInWithLogonNameExchange",
  "Override": true,
  "Value": "Broker Sign In"
},
```

However, I'd like to change the AAD button text. 
Is there a way to change the button copy text?

That button looks like this:

> AAD mydomain.com

So I added the following:

```
{
  "ElementType": "ClaimsProvider",
  "ElementId": null,
  "StringId": "mydomain.com",
  "Override": true,
  "Value": "Underwriter Sign In"
},
```

I get the following when I attempt to upload it:

> 1 Validation errors found in upload overrides for api.idpselections. Please ensure that your uploaded resource matches the template: The localized string with ElementType: ClaimsProvider and StringId: mydomain.com is not a valid override.

If I set override to false, the file uploads but the setting does not change.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the button text using [localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization).

See [the "Customize your strings" section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization#customize-your-strings) for how to customize any UI string.

E.g.:

```
{
  "ElementType": "UxElement",
  "StringId": "button_continue",
  "Override": true,
  "Value": "Click me"
}
```

Comment: Ok this works great, **except** . . . the button I want to re-leable is not in the default file and adding some JSON doesn't seem to work, unless I am doing it wrong. Please see updates.

Comment: For `ElementType` of `ClaimsProvider`, then `StringId` should refer to the display name of the claims provider.